# While using drawer navigation getting error - toggleDrawer() is not a function error

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am creating a react native application where I have a component app header that has a menu icon and when we press that the drawer should open but it is giving error that -

```
 ERROR  TypeError: navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
```

Here is that component where I am using toggleDrawer() -

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen'
import { background_color, light_red, primary_color } from '../util/Colors'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

export default function AppHeader({screenName}) {
  const navigation=useNavigation();

  
  const handleWallet=()=>{
    navigation.navigate('Wallet');
  }
  const handleLanguage=()=>{

  }
  const handleSupport=()=>{
    navigation.navigate('Customer Support')
  }

  const handleMenu=()=>{
    navigation.toggleDrawer();
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleMenu}>
      <Ionicons name='menu' size={30} color={background_color}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{screenName}</Text>
      <View style={styles.sideIcon}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleWallet}>
        <Image source={require('../Assets/wallet.png')} style={{ tintColor: background_color, width: 24, height:24 }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLanguage}>
        <Image source={require('../Assets/language.png')} style={{ tintColor: background_color, width: 24, height:24 }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSupport}>
        <Image source={require('../Assets/support.png')} style={{ tintColor: background_color, width: 24, height:24 }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    width:wp(100),
    height:55,
    backgroundColor:primary_color,
    alignItems:"center",
    flexDirection:"row",
    paddingHorizontal:20,
    gap:20,
    marginBottom:8
  },
  title:{
    color:background_color,
    fontSize:18,
    fontWeight:"bold"
  },
  sideIcon:{
    position:"absolute", 
    right:0,
    gap:18,
    flexDirection:"row",
    alignItems:"center",
    marginRight:20
  }
})
```

And also I have two more buttons wallet and customer support they are also not working and showing error -

```
 The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Customer Support"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'Customer Support'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.
```

According to me my Navigation is set up correctly here is Navigation.js -

```
import {Image} from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LogInviaPhone from '../Screens/LogInviaPhone';
import LogInviaEmail from '../Screens/LogInviaEmail';
import OTPScreen from '../Screens/OTPScreen';
import OTPScreenEmail from '../Screens/OTPScreenEmail';
import HomeScreen from '../Screens/HomeScreen';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Call from '../Screens/Call';
import Live from '../Screens/Live';
import Chat from '../Screens/Chat';
import Pooja from '../Screens/Pooja';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign'
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'
import Foundation from 'react-native-vector-icons/Foundation'
import { background_color, primary_color, secondary_color } from '../util/Colors';
import History from '../Screens/History';
import Wallet from '../Screens/Wallet';
import Favorite from '../Screens/Favorite';
import Refer from '../Screens/Refer';
import FreeService from '../Screens/FreeService';
import AstrologerRegistration from '../Screens/AstrologerRegistration';
import CustomerSupport from '../Screens/CustomerSupport';
import Mall from '../Screens/Mall';
import Settings from '../Screens/Settings';
import MyFollowing from '../Screens/MyFollowing';
import CustomDrawer from './CustomDrawer';
import { appName } from '../util/AppDetails';
// import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
// import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';
// import { getCountry } from "react-native-localize";
// import ISO3166 from 'iso-3166-1-alpha-2';
// import {NetworkInfo} from 'react-native-network-info';
// import axios from 'axios'
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import Share from '../Screens/Share';
import RateUs from '../Screens/RateUs';
import UserDetails from '../Screens/UserDetails';
import AppHeader from '../Components/AppHeader';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const Stack=createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab=createBottomTabNavigator();
const Drawer=createDrawerNavigator();

const MainTab=()=>{
  return(
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
      tabBarStyle:{
        backgroundColor:background_color,
        height:55,
        paddingBottom:5,
        paddingTop:5,
        paddingHorizontal:3
      },
      tabBarActiveTintColor:"black",
      tabBarLabelStyle:{
        fontSize:12
      },
      headerShown:false
    }}>
      <Tab.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} options={{
        tabBarIcon:({ color, size }) => (<Feather name="home" size={20} color={color} />),
      }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name='Call' component={Call} options={{
        tabBarIcon:({ color, size }) => (<Ionicons name="call-outline" size={20} color={color} />),
      }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name='Live' component={Live} options={{
        tabBarIcon:({ color, size }) => (<Feather name="video" size={20} color={color} />),
      }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name='Chat' component={Chat} options={{
        tabBarIcon:({ color, size }) => (<Ionicons name="chatbubbles-outline" size={20} color={color} />),
      }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name='Pooja' component={Pooja} options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <Image source={require('../Assets/kalash.png')} style={{ tintColor: color, width: 22, height: 22 }} />
        )
      }}/>
      <Tab.Screen name='Mall' component={Mall} options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="shopping" size={20} color={color} />)
      }}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

const MainDrawer=({navigation})=>{
  return(
    <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{
      drawerContentStyle:{
        height:10,
      },
      drawerLabelStyle:{
        marginVertical:-8,
        paddingLeft:10,
        textAlign:"left",
        marginLeft:-15,
      },
      drawerStyle:{
        width:wp(80)
      },
      drawerActiveBackgroundColor:secondary_color,
      drawerActiveTintColor:"black",
      headerShown:false
    }}
    
    drawerContent={props=> <CustomDrawer {...props}/>}>
      <Drawer.Screen name='Home Screen' component={MainTab} options={{
        title:" Home",
        drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<Foundation name="home" size={20} color={color} />),
        }}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name='Chat' component={Chat} options={{
        title:"Chat with Astrologer",
        drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<Ionicons name="chatbubbles" size={20} color={color} />),
      }}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name='Call' component={Call} options={{
        title:"Call Astrologer",
        drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<Ionicons name="call" size={20} color={color} />)
      }}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name='Live' component={Live} options={{
        title:"Astrologer Live",
        drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<Ionicons name="videocam" size={20} color={color} />)
      }}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name='Pooja' component={Pooja} options={{
        title:"Book a Pooja",
        drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (
          <Image source={require('../Assets/kalash.png')} style={{ tintColor: color, width: 20, height: size }} />
        )
      }}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name='History' component={History} options={{
        title:"Order History",
        drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<MaterialIcons name="history" size={20} color={color} />)
      }}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name='Wallet' component={Wallet} options={{
        title:"Wallet Transaction",
        drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<Ionicons name="wallet" size={20} color={color} />)
      }}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name='Favorite' component={Favorite} options={{
        drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<MaterialIcons name="favorite" size={20} color={color} />)
      }}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name='Refer' component={Refer} options={{
        title:"Refer to Friend",
        drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="share" size={20} color={color} />)
      }}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name='Astro Mall' component={Mall} options={{
        drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="shopping" size={20} color={color} />)
      }}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name='My Followings' component={MyFollowing} options={{
        drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (
          <Image source={require('../Assets/following.png')} style={{ tintColor: color, width: 20, height: 20 }} />
          )
        }}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Customer Support' component={CustomerSupport} options={{
          drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<AntDesign name="customerservice" size={20} color={color} />)
        }}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Free Service' component={FreeService} options={{
          drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (
            <Image source={require('../Assets/free.png')} style={{ tintColor: color, width: 20, height: 20 }} />
            )
          }}/>
          <Drawer.Screen name='Register as Astrologer' component={AstrologerRegistration} options={{
            title:" Register as Astrologer",
            drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<FontAwesome name="user" size={20} color={color} />)
          }}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Settings' component={Settings} options={{
          drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<Ionicons name="settings-sharp" size={20} color={color} />)
        }}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Share' component={Share} options={{
          drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<Ionicons name="share-social" size={20} color={color} />)
        }}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Rate Us' component={RateUs} options={{
          drawerIcon:({ color, size }) => (<Feather name="star" size={20} color={color} />)
        }}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function Navigation() {
  const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(false);
  const [country,setCountry]=useState(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
    AsyncStorage.getItem('persist:root').then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        const persistedState = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data).auth);
        setIsAuthorized(persistedState.isAuthenticated);
      }
    });
    const fetchCountry=async()=>{
      const request = await fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=6cae93b1bf8907")
      const jsonResponse = await request.json()

      console.log(jsonResponse.ip, jsonResponse.country)
      setCountry(jsonResponse.country)
    }

    fetchCountry();
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Country ",country); // Log the country name whenever it changes
  }, [country]);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
        headerShown:false
      }}>
      {country === 'IN' ? (
        <Stack.Screen name='Phone Login' component={LogInviaPhone} />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name='Email Login' component={LogInviaEmail} />
          )}
          <Stack.Screen name='OTP Phone' component={OTPScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Main Drawer' component={MainDrawer} />
        <Stack.Screen name='OTP Email' component={OTPScreenEmail} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Home Screen' component={MainTab} />
        <Stack.Screen name='User Details' component={UserDetails} options={{
          headerShown:true,
          title:"Profile"
        }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='Header' component={AppHeader}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

What should I do I tried navigation prop and useNavigation both It was working earlier but suddenly started showing this error also I have to apply a condition here that if user has authorized then he should directly navigate to home screen but because of this navigation issue it is not working and I had to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#props), this does not work.

> Note that you cannot use the useNavigation hook inside the
> drawerContent since useNavigation is only available inside screens.
> You get a navigation prop for your drawerContent which you can use
> instead:

I have created an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/afd6c8) for my solution approach.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { forwardRef, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

function Feed({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Open drawer"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.openDrawer();
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="Toggle drawer"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.toggleDrawer();
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function Notifications() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Notifications Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Close drawer"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.closeDrawer()}
      />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Toggle drawer"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

// Add the forwardRef
const MyDrawer = forwardRef(function MyDrawer(_props, ref) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={(props) => {
        ref.current = props.navigation; // Set the ref with your Drawer reference
        return <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />;
      }}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  const drawerNavRef = useRef();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <View
        style={{ height: 250, justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
        <Pressable
          onPress={() => {
            drawerNavRef.current.toggleDrawer(); // Access your drawer outside from Drawer.Navigator
          }}>
          <Text>Header Toggle</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
      <MyDrawer ref={drawerNavRef} />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: But I tried using navigation prop also but still same error

Comment: The function won't be available in ```AppHeader```, how should AppHeader know which Drawer should be toggled?
The toggle function is only available with the Drawer, maybe you can use a forwardRef to expose the the function to ```AppHeader```.